# How do I properly use files in an Eclipse project hierarchy using runtime and processes?

Tags: java, windows, command-line, wireless

So I'm calling up the following command in my Java project:

`process = rt.exec("netsh wlan add profile filename="[fileNameHere]"`

In order to automatically import wireless profiles in Windows.

I have placed the wireless networking .xml profiles in the following folder in my Eclipse project hierarchy,
`/src/NetworkProfiles/[fileName.xml]`

What's a good way to have my process point to the location of where I placed my .xml files when I build as an executable .jar?

I want to avoid using absolute pathing (like explicitly hardcoding `C:/Users/...`) due to the fact that users can place my executable .jar file anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe

```
URL url = getClass().getResource("/NetworkProfiles/[fileName.xml]");

File file = new File(url.getPath());
```

could help you

Comment: This works when I'm in Eclipse myself, but not when I export as a runnable .jar file.

Comment: Sorry @Andrew, my mistake, didn't see the "build as an executable .jar" part

Comment: That's fine - it was an honest mistake :) I appreciate your help nonetheless.